# How to read route parameters and navigate to details page

Tags: angular

I am using JSONPlaceholder, from which I want to read and render all posts one by one. When I click on title of a post it should take me to the detail page of that particular post. I've created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-6xlhe1) also. Click on *All posts* from navbar. Let me explain my code here.

**post.service.ts**

```
import { ...} from '@angular/core';
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {
  private postsUrl = '/posts';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  // fetch all posts
  getAllPosts():Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }

  //fetch specific post
  getPostByID(id: number): Observable<Post> {
    console.log("getPostByID called");
    const url = `${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Post>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('getPost: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      );
  }
}
```

**post-details.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
...

@Component({
  templateUrl: './post-details.component.html',
})
export class PostDetails {
  errorMessage="";
  post: Post;
  pageTitle = 'Product Detail';

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute, private postService: PostService) {
  }

  getPost(id: number) {
    console.log("getPost called");
    this.postService.getPostByID(id).subscribe({
      next: post => {
        this.onPostRetrieved(post);
      },
      error: err => this.errorMessage = err
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    const id=+this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id');
    console.log(id);
    this.getPost(id);
  }

  onPostRetrieved(post: Post): void {
    this.post = post;
    console.log("onPostRetrieved called");
    if (this.post) {
      this.pageTitle = `Product Detail: ${this.post.title}`;
    } else {
      this.pageTitle = 'No product found';
    }
  }
}
```

There is no error but I'm not getting the details. And console also looks Ok, see:

[image]

I noticed that control is not going inside *onPostRetrieved()*. I checked for solution but I'm not able to fix this. Please correct me.

Comment: The problem is in **post.service.ts**. The URL that you're passing to _getPostByID()_ is not complete.

Comment: but the path works fine with postman. I have checked it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your incomplete URL. See what's happening. You've:

`private postsUrl='/posts';`

When this goes inside your *getPostByID*, you've:

`const url=${this.postsUrl}/${id}`

which makes the complete URL something like: `/posts/1` while correct URL should look like: `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts/1`.

So what you can do is provide a full correct URL:

```
import { ...} from '@angular/core';
...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PostService {
  private postsUrl = 'https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts';
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {}

  // fetch all posts
  getAllPosts():Observable<Post[]> {
    return this.httpClient.get<Post[]>('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  }

  //fetch specific post
  getPostByID(id: number): Observable<Post> {
    console.log("getPostByID called");
    const url = `${this.postsUrl}/${id}`;
    return this.httpClient.get<Post>(url)
      .pipe(
        tap(data => console.log('getPost: ' + JSON.stringify(data)))
      );
  }
```

I've a better implementation but let's first try this. Because you'll face CORS errors with this kind of coding. Good luck.

PS: Here's a live demo on [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wj7s4q)

Comment: Oh, now I see. Thanks for correcting. This solved my problem.

Comment: Happy to help :-)